# Memory leak on Delegates with Callbacks

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, delegates, callback

```
 public delegate void SendCallbackType();

  public class SenderBase
  {
      SenderBase()
      {
         mySend = new SendCallbackType(SendData);
         mySend.BeginInvoke(SendCallback, null);
      }

    void SendData()
    {              
         // process / sending data
    }

    void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {      
        **SendCallbackType worker = (SendCallbackType)((AsyncResult)ar).AsyncDelegate;
         worker.EndInvoke(ar);**

        //Above code is mandatory ? Working fine without them.

         mySend.BeginInvoke(SendCallback, null);

}

 // Test
  Dictionary<SenderBase> SenderCollection = new Dictionary();
  SenderCollection.Add(new SenderBase()); 
  SenderCollection.Remove(0);
 // Add and remove seven times
```

The objects (SenderBase) are not garbage Collected. They are keep moving to next generations.

Using RedAnts Memory Profiler,

[image]

Any suggestions to clean up the object.

Thanks.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1774202/not-calling-delegate-endinvoke-can-cause-memory-leak-a-myth for a similar question. No there is no memory leak as long as the delegate and the using class share the same lifespan.

Comment: If no memory leak , no need to use EndInvoke() ?

Comment: Your SendCallback() looks a bit recursive...

Comment: Based on empirical data there is no need to use EndInvoke.

Answer (score 5):

You keep calling mySend.BeginInvoke().  So the garbage collector always sees a reference to the mySend object on the stack of the threadpool threads.  And thus won't collect it.  And the code keeps running forever of course.

Not calling EndInvoke() in this scenario is a Bad Idea, it leaks resources for 10 minutes for each BeginInvoke() call.  The default remoting lifetime, remoting is the underlying plumbing that implements a delegate's BeginInvoke() method.

Hard to come up with suggestions to clean up the code, it just doesn't make much sense to do this.  You might as well start a thread with a while(true) {} loop.  That will definitely be more efficient.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I need recursive here.I thought delegates (using ThreadPool thread) no overhead if i add/remove instances from Dictionary. Nearly 900 objects are added during the application lifetime. And endinvoke(), I dont want to cath exceptions ( the exception are caught inside senddata (not posted(raise through events))) and the senddata is completed when callback is called. Any other reasons for endinvoke?

Comment: The threadpool thread was automatically dead after i I removed the instance. After removing the object from Dictionary. I no longer need that. I have tried null the delegate. But remains same.

Comment: Your comments are as inscrutable as your code.  I don't think I can help you.

Comment: Kindly refer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11469370/asynchronous-delegates-vs-threads